# How to manipulate the order of the Before-/AfterScenarios in JBehave?

Tags: java, maven, annotations, jbehave

In our project we are currently encountering multiple Before-/AfterScenarios, which all by definition get executed before/after every Scenario. However some of the methods are dependent on the execution of the others.

More precisely: A third party framework uses BeforeScenario in their code, that should always be executed before our BeforeScenario. JBehave has a way of prioritizing steps when it comes to chosing the correct step for execution.

```
@Then(value="the value returned is empty", priority=1)
public void theValueIsEmpty()

@Then("the value returned is $value")
public void theValueIs(String value)
```

Is there something similar for the Before-/AfterScenario annotation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to order execution of `@BeforeScenario`/`@AfterScenrio` in JBehave. But you can try using new `Lifecycle` functionality:

```
Lifecycle:
Before:
Scope: SCENARIO
[steps to be executed before each scenario]
After:
Scope: SCENARIO
[steps to be executed after each scenario]
```

More details can be found in the official documentation: [Lifecycle](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/lifecycle.html)

Alternative approach: file a new [JIRA](http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/issue-tracking.html) ticket for Before/After prioritizing and implement it or wait for implementation from JBehave contributors.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your Answer! Unfortunately the Lifecycle and the Before and Afterstories are what we are trying to away from currently in order to have only Given-When-Then in our stories to keep only our business language there. I will issue a JIRA ticket for it